# WPF Newbie Questions - How to Create a Control Container

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF and would like to find out the best way to disable controls under a RadioButton with one line of code.  With Windows Forms this is accomplished with a Panel.  I went down the path of using a Canvas but that brought up yet another question.  Why can't I drag and drop controls onto the canvas?  Instead I succeeded by moving the XML by hand.  This brought yet another question. If the Canvas is made too small the controls are not clipped.  Here's a screen shot of a screen I'm working on.  Sorry for the newbie question.  Thanks in advance for your help with this.

[image]

Comment: A couple quick notes: (1) The WPF designer is not (and I'd argue cannot be) as good as the forms designer. It can provide a convenient preview, sometimes, but learn to xaml for the sake of your own sanity. :) (2) Try using a Grid to define your layout. It's quite flexible and really the go-to option. (3) Once you have a grid, you can put other panels into it for layout purposes (canvas is probably the least good option, it doesn't clip by design). I think disabling the children will happen if you disable the parent.

Answer (score 0):

WPF uses panels to manage layout. You can find a series of panels in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you're learning, I'd recommend playing with `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, and `Grid` in that order. Canvas can be useful, but typically for more advanced scenarios. (It doesn't clip by design, e.g.)

You can certainly nest panels within panels to create a visual hierarchy. I've often used dockpanels containing grids containing stackpanels, e.g. Disabling the panel ought to disable the children of the panel appropriately (though it's been a couple years since I've worked in WPF, now, so I'm a bit rusty- I don't think there has to be an explicit binding but I could be wrong).

If you develop a drag-drop workflow with the WPF designer that works well, make a blog and a youtube video. I'd like to learn it, b/c I never figured out how. :)